# how to populate language with country list using knockoutJS

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Onclick a list of language how to display the respective countries in another list using knockoutJS ?

I write my json like below:

```
var LanguageLists = '{"LanguageLists":[' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Afrikaans"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Albanian"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Arabic"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Bengali"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Bosnian"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Cantonese"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Chinese"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Danish"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Dutch"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "English"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Finnish"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "French"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "German"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Greek"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Hindi"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Irish"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Italian"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Japanese"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Korean"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Lingala"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Malay"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Moldovan"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Nepali"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Northern Sotho"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Persian"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Portuguese"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Romanian"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Russian"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Serbian"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Somali"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Spanish"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Tamil"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Tsonga"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Turkish"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Urdu"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Venda"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Xhosa"}]},' +
    '{ "LanguageList": [{ "LangListItem": "Zulu"}]}' +
    ']}';

var parsedLanguageListJson = ko.utils.parseJson(LanguageLists);
```

and the HTML like below

```
<div class="flexColumnStyle01 containerStyle02">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: myLangListViewModel.LanguageLists">
        <li data-bind="foreach: $data.LanguageList"> <a data-bind="html:LangListItem, click: $parent.removePlace"></a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="flexColumnStyle01 containerStyle03">
    <ul>
        <li> <a></a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now can anyone help how to populate the respective countries in "**containerStyle03**" list ?

Comment: Why do you write JSON literals in JavaScript? That's completely unnecessary. Just use a regular object.

Comment: Please post sample code in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for your problem. Modify your code something like this.

You need to have an array something like this

```
var LanguageLists = [ 
    { "LangListItem": "English","Country":"England","Code":"UK"},
    { "LangListItem": "English","Country":"Australia","Code":"AS"},
    { "LangListItem": "Frunch","Country":"France","Code":"FR"},
    { "LangListItem": "German","Country":"Ditch","Code":"GR"},
    { "LangListItem": "Arabic","Country":"Saudi Arabia","Code":"SA"},
    { "LangListItem": "Arabic","Country":"Dubai","Code":"DU"},
]
```

And now your view

```
<div class="flexColumnStyle01 containerStyle02">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: myLangListViewModel.LanguageLists">
         <li data-bind="foreach: $data.LanguageList"> 
              <a data-bind="html:LangListItem, click: $parent.showCountries"></a>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

And here is the `showCountries` function

```
self.showCountries = function(country){
     var countries = []
     ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.LanguageLists,function(item){
        if(item.Country == country){
                countries.push(item.Country)
        }
     })
     self.CountryList(countries)
}
```

Where `CountryList` is observable array property.

And view

```
<div class="flexColumnStyle01 containerStyle03">
    <ul data-bind="foreach:CountryList">
        <li data-bind="text:$data"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Raheel, Even in my code also is populating languages list. but i want the respective country list need to be display in another panel, while clicking each languages.you got my question ?

Comment: i am afraid i dont understand what you mean. can you explain it fully?

Comment: ok, I want the interface like where left side i need the list of languages (like, english, spanish,etc...) and the right side there is an empty list panel. when the user clicks on left side any of languages, than the right side panel respective country(like if its english - then us, uk, australi such countries) list need to be populate/show... how ?

Comment: ok. But tell me how are we going to tell our model UK , Australia and other countries are related to English. You do not have anything to make relation.

Comment: Thats what i need, do v need to create separate array for that? or tell me the best approach to achieve that ?